# Find the time complexity of a given function

Tags: java, time-complexity

For the given program what will be the time complexity.

```
int count = 0;

    for(int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

To my understanding, it should be `O(nlogn)` because the `i` loop is divide and conquer and hence `O(logn)` and the `j` loop is `O(n)`.

However, the correct answer is `O(n)`. Can someone explain why?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: the worst case for inner loop is O(n) so yes it will be O(n)

Comment: There is no silver bullet to get the complexity, and sometimes literal expressions can't even be written.  In this case you're right it is `O(N*lg2N)`.

Comment: The correct answer is O(n)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's `O(n)`:

The outer loop has `O(logn)` iterations, since `i` starts at `n` and gets halved on each iteration.

Now let's consider the number of iterations of the inner loop:

- In the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop has `n` iterations (since `i==n`).
- In the second iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop has `n`/2 iterations (since `i==n/2`).
- ...
- In the `log(n)`'th (and final) iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop has 1 iteration (since `i==1`).

Summing all the inner loop iterations we get:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 <= 2*n = O(n)
```

Comment: Will it not be considered, the outer loop.

Comment: @Rudra well, when `i` reaches 1 (the last iteration of the outer loop), the inner loop goes from 0 to 1, which means it has one iteration.

Comment: Thank you.
The outer loop is increasing the computation by log(n). Why we are not considering it.

Comment: @Rudra I think it is because while the J loop is O(n) time, that n is dependent on i, which halves every iteration.

Comment: @Rudra Only if each step of the inner loop had taken `O(n)` time, the total time would have been `O(nlogn)`. Since the inner loop has a different running time in each iteration, you can't just multiply `n` by `logn`.